# What characters should, and should I absolutely not use in generated passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-policy

I'm currently setting up a KeePass database after switching over from another password manager, and it has the option to change the character set for generating a password.

This has a lot of options, but now I'm wondering if you could possibly use all of the given characters,

[image]

Upper-case, lower-case and digits would obviously be no issue.

But how about the other characters? Why would a website disable you from using certain characters? The only thing I can think of is that the space could get forwarded incorrectly, and that enabling brackets could make your system vulnurable for xss attacks.

Comment: some sites might filter all markup or code-like characters (including quotes?)...  those extended ascii characters would be pretty confusing if you ever had to type them yourself.  Different fonts might display different characters there, and who knows what would happen on the back-end depending on the native language's base unicode setting.

Comment: From a security standpoint, you should not be constrained in the characters that you use (assuming the server is not vulnerable to nonprinting character exploits). The more possible characters there are for a given password length, the harder it is to crack. The websites you visit limit your options at the expense of your security. That said, I don't know of any good heuristics to avoid poorly designed security protocols by limiting your password characters.

Comment: You've asked 2 very different questions: 1) what chars should I not use? and 2) why don't sites allow all chars? The answers are 1) use as many as the site allows. and 2) there are lots of different reasons.